# Why a black screen with sample code in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut

I have this OpenGL program, a fragment shader, and a vertex shader.

This is the program source

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include "ogldev_util.h"
#include "ogldev_math_3d.h"

GLuint VBO;

const char* pVSFileName = "shader.vs";
const char* pFSFileName = "shader.fs";

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    Vector3f Vertices[3];
    Vertices[0] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[2] = Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

static void AddShader(GLuint ShaderProgram, const char* pShaderText, GLenum ShaderType)
{
    GLuint ShaderObj = glCreateShader(ShaderType);

    if (ShaderObj == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader type %d\n", ShaderType);
        exit(0);
    }

    const GLchar* p[1];
    p[0] = pShaderText;
    GLint Lengths[1];
    Lengths[0]= strlen(pShaderText);
    glShaderSource(ShaderObj, 1, p, Lengths);
    glCompileShader(ShaderObj);
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(ShaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        GLchar InfoLog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderObj, 1024, NULL, InfoLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", ShaderType, InfoLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, ShaderObj);
}

static void CompileShaders()
{
    GLuint ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    if (ShaderProgram == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader program\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    string vs, fs;

    if (!ReadFile(pVSFileName, vs)) {
        exit(1);
    };

    if (!ReadFile(pFSFileName, fs)) {
        exit(1);
    };

    AddShader(ShaderProgram, vs.c_str(), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    AddShader(ShaderProgram, fs.c_str(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint Success = 0;
    GLchar ErrorLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Success);
    if (Success == 0) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error linking shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &Success);
    if (!Success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 04");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    // Must be done after glut is initialized!
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
      return 1;
    }

    printf("GL version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CreateVertexBuffer();

    CompileShaders();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

This vertex shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(0.5 * Position.x, 0.5 * Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);
}
```

and this fragment shader

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The result is a [black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni80e.png) And i wonder why

Is somebody having an hint ?
(I'm using an integrated Intel GPU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vertex Array Objects (VAOs)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) are capital-R Required in Core contexts.

Make sure you create/bind/populate one before attempting to `glDraw*()`.

Comment: Thank you very much !